# How to list errors from a custom external command in Vim

Tags: vim

When using vim, I would like to use a custom command to build my projects.

The build command looks as following

```
matmake2 -t gcc-debug
```

Optimally I would like to use vims built in error buffer, so that I could use `:copen` to view and navigate the errors, but the results from running

```
:!matmake2 -t gcc-debug
```

is not picked up by vims error parser, and when trying to set

```
set makeprg='matmake2 -t gcc-debug'
```

in my vimrc-file, I get the error "Unknown flag -t".

Is there any way so that I can run my custom build command with arguments in a way so that vims error parser will pick it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors picked up by Vim end up in the quickfix list. There are many commands that can populate that list but `:!<whatever>` is not one of them.

What you need is the `:help :make` command, which calls the program defined with `:help 'makeprg'`, parses its output against the various patterns in `:help 'errorformat'`, and populates the `:help quickfix` list with valid errors.

You were on the right track with:

```
set makeprg='matmake2 -t gcc-debug'
```

but string options don't take expressions as value. You can set `makeprg` this way:

```
set makeprg=matmake2\ -t\ gcc-debug
```

or that way:

```
let &makeprg = 'matmake2 -t gcc-debug'
```

with either of the two lines above in your config, you should be able to do `:make %` and then `:copen` to see your errors.

Comment: Thanks! I do really have a lot to learn with vim-scripting. And I checked the :help make before, but after your tip i reallized that there was more interesting information if i just scrolled down a bit further.

Comment: I wouldn't call that "vim-scripting". FWIW, the built-in user manual has a whole section dedicated to introducing that very topic: `:h 30.1`.